# Could the universe behave like a Bose-Einstein condensate in the distant future?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate

Question:

If the universe keeps expanding and getting cooler, and the temperature asymptotically approaches absolute zero over time...

[image]

Could the universe behave like a Bose-Einstein condensate in the distant future?

[image]

Density distribution of a Bose-Einstein condensate

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, no.

Bose-Einstein condensation is driven by increase in phase-space density, quantified by the degeneracy parameter $D$:
$$ D = n_0 \lambda_{\text{dB}}^3,$$
where $n_0$ is the peak density in real space, and $\lambda_{\text{dB}}$ is the de Broglie (thermal $\propto T^{-1/2}$) wavelength, quantifiying the extent in momentum space.

The degeneracy parameter is related to the entropy $S$ and the 'container' shape $\gamma$ as:
$$ D \propto \exp \left (\gamma - \frac{S}{N k_B} \right ), $$
where $\gamma = 0$ in the absence of a trapping potential, $N$ is the number of particles, and $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant.

Bose-Einstein condensation kicks in when $D \sim 1$.

To achieve that, you have to *remove entropy* from your system. The laser and evaporative cooling techniques that have so far achieved BEC of cold atoms, photons, & co. not only reduce the temperature of the sample, but also its entropy. The change in entropy being $\geq 0$ in any process, you are basically extracting entropy from the sample to the environment -- casing point, laser cooling: you send in a directional laser beam (low entropy), and it comes out as spontaneously emitted (more disordered, higher entropy).

In the case of the universe expansion:

- slow expansions are usually *adiabatic*, i.e. at constant entropy. Particles in their ground state stay in their ground state and, sure, get "cooler". But they also increase their spatial profile and hence maintain constant phase space density.
- Assuming the universe has too high an entropy $S$ to Bose-Condense now, if will only have a *higher* entropy in the future. To reduce it, you'd have to dump it somewhere *outside* the system (the Universe...) - and if you figure that one out, let me know.

---

From an engineering point of view, like the other answer & comments therein say, you also have problems. Low densities mean low thermalisation rates. Large particle separation bring more thermalisation issues and even causality and relativistic issues.

Comment: …and what about Helium-4 (when the temperature of the universe asymptotically approaches absolute zero over time)? Helium-4 makes up about one quarter of the ordinary matter in the universe by mass. The total spin of the helium-4 nucleus is an integer (zero), and therefore it is a boson (as are neutral atoms of helium-4). The superfluid behavior is now understood to be a manifestation of Bose–Einstein condensation.

Comment: Bec and superfluids are not technically the same thing. But sure, the He might BEC condense. Provided the expansion manages to extract entropy from He to the rest of the matter in the universe. Just by expansion, it seems to me that everything is adiabatic so constant entropy.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that a superfluid around the galaxies has already developed long ago. https://penntoday.upenn.edu/news/physicist-theorizes-dark-matter-superfluid
Maybe at temperatures near absolute zero, when the energy sources (all stars in the galaxies) have run out of fuel, what remains from the universe is a superfluid [Bose-Einstein-condensate], a single wave function.

Answer (score 0):

No, because a BEC requires not only incredibly cold temperatures but high enough densities as well. You can have a gas approach absolute zero just as easily as long as the particles remain non-interacting, which they would do if they remain incredibly far apart relative to their size.

As the universe expands, it not only gets cooler but also more rarified. Eventually even fundamental particles will be outside the range to interact with any other particle even if they moved at lightspeed for infinite time towards each other.

Comment: Yes. But it is also worth noting that BEC formation also requires the density to be *low* enough as well (i.e. in a goldilocks zone). If the density is too high, then the probability of three-body collisions becomes too high, and that's a bad thing because those collisions can shift energy in between the three bodies and lead to the formation of dimers (and eventually bigger molecules, all the way up to regular condensation).

Comment: One should also mention that temperature alone does not drive Bose Einstein condensation. It's increase in phase-space density. And phase space density is proportional to $\exp(-S)$, where $S$ is the entropy. So if you go slow, stuff just adiabatically follows the ground state with no change in entropy. Also, if the whole universe if your system, there's no place to dump the excess entropy you'd be removing to make a sub-system condense.